# clear screen returning 256 in python

Tags: python, macos

I am using mac. I wrote the below code to clear the screen

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('clear')
```

it should clear the screen but its returning 256

its returning 1 for

```
 import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call("clear")
```

Comment: Did you try: `>>> _ = os.system('clear')`?

Comment: Why don't you show the actual code *and output* you get?

Comment: am getting just 256 only and check my edit

Comment: Does the `clear` command actually work in the shell (not from python)? I've never used Os X so I have no idea whether there *is* a `clear` command there.

Comment: i am on Python 3.4.1 shell @Bakuriu

Comment: Yes, close that shell and type `clear` in the *terminal*. Python cannot invent programs that don't exist. If the actual Os X terminal doesn't provide a `clear` command *obviously* trying to call such a command will result in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run `os.system('clear')` on Ubuntu 11.04 alternate : it cleared the screen.
The return value you get depends on the operating system as [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) states:

> Note that POSIX does not specify the meaning of the return value of
>   the C system() function, so the return value of the Python function is
>   system-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue here. (and yes guys, 'clear' command on OSX terminal is like "cls" on windows.)

This solved my problem: use the terminal, not the Visual Studio Code Terminal, os IDLE (Python) Terminal. But the original Mac OSX terminal.